# A diamond-inheritance problem

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

Just for fun I am working on a XUL implementation for Windows. In XUL, UI elements can be written in XML like this:

```
<window width="800" height="600"></window>
```

I am considering a system for getting and setting element attributes. It's working pretty well but I am not certain if the use of diamond inheritance is potentially hazardous here. I've posted a complete code sample below:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <map>


class Attribute
{
public:
    virtual void get(std::string & outValue) = 0;
    virtual void set(const std::string & inValue) = 0;

    static int String2Int(const std::string & inString)
    {
        return boost::lexical_cast<int>(inString);
    }

    static std::string Int2String(int inValue)
    {
        return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(inValue);
    }
};


class Width : public Attribute
{
public:
    Width(){}

    virtual void get(std::string & outValue)
    {
        outValue = Int2String(getWidth());
    }

    virtual void set(const std::string & inValue)
    {
        setWidth(String2Int(inValue));
    }

    virtual int getWidth() const = 0;

    virtual void setWidth(int inWidth) = 0;
};


class Height : public Attribute
{
public:
    Height(){}

    virtual void get(std::string & outValue)
    {
        outValue = Int2String(getHeight());
    }

    virtual void set(const std::string & inValue)
    {
        setHeight(String2Int(inValue));
    }

    virtual int getHeight() const = 0;

    virtual void setHeight(int inHeight) = 0;
};

class Element : public Width,  // concerning the is-a vs has-a philosophy
                public Height  //   => see my note below
{
public:
    Element() :
        mWidth(0),
        mHeight(0)
    {
        // STATIC CAST NEEDED HERE OTHERWISE WE GET COMPILER ERROR:
        // error C2594: '=' : ambiguous conversions from 'Element *const ' to 'Attribute *'
        mAttrControllers["width"] = static_cast<Width*>(this);
        mAttrControllers["height"] = static_cast<Height*>(this);
    }

    void setAttribute(const std::string & inAttrName, const std::string & inAttrValue)
    {
        Attributes::iterator it = mAttrControllers.find(inAttrName);
        if (it != mAttrControllers.end())
        {
            Attribute * attribute = it->second;
            attribute->set(inAttrValue);
        }
    }

    std::string getAttribute(const std::string & inAttrName)
    {
        std::string result;
        Attributes::iterator it = mAttrControllers.find(inAttrName);
        if (it != mAttrControllers.end())
        {
            Attribute * attribute = it->second;
            attribute->get(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    virtual int getWidth() const
    {
        return mWidth;
    }

    virtual void setWidth(int inWidth)
    {
        mWidth = inWidth;
    }

    virtual int getHeight() const
    {
        return mHeight;
    }

    virtual void setHeight(int inHeight)
    {
        mHeight = inHeight;
    }

private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, Attribute *> Attributes;
    Attributes mAttrControllers;
    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;
};


int main()
{
    Element el;
    el.setAttribute("width", "800");
    el.setAttribute("height", "600");
    int w = el.getWidth();
    int h = el.getHeight();
    return 0;
}
```

I think it's ok since the base class Attributes has no data members, so no conflicts can arise there. But I thought I'd check with the community. Your insights are much appreciated!

**Edit**
About the "is-a" vs "has-a", and "favor composition over inheritance" remarks I have this to say:

- There
  is an advantage to inheritance here.
  If Element inherits Width then it is
  forced to implement the getWidth and
  setWidth methods. So adding an
  attribute implies an 'automatic'
  update of Element's interface.
- I originally named these classes
  AttributeController, WidthController
  and HeightController, but I found
  them too verbose. You could say that my Element is an Attribute controller. (Ok, that's lame, but not untrue!)
- Further proof: the definitions of Width and Height
  do not contain any data members. The
  Element class actually *has* them.
  The Width and Height classes only
  provide the interfaces. So it's more of a *can-do* relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure what all those classes are buying you - seems awfully complicated for what it's doing. Do you actually gain anything by having the attributes as separate classes? It looks to me like you'd do just as well with them as simple variables, or just keep them in a map<string, int>.

Comment: The type is not always int, it can be an enum or a bool as well. And more often than not I don't store the attribute values but I forward them to system calls like setWindowText, getWindowText etc...

Comment: "If Element inherits Width then it is forced to implement the getWidth and setWidth methods" - and who does this benefit? As I understand it, you'll be the one writing this code. users simply have to define their XUL xmls. And since you know that an Element should implement getWidth/setWidth, you don't really need to abuse inheritance for it. I don't like the dual role of Height/Width as *both* ad hoc interfaces for Element, *and* as attributes in their own right. (You have a Width object with a getWidth() method, which doesn't actually return a Width? ;))

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Why would you want to force the user to implement getWidth etc? Would it not be better to have a getWidth() member which returned a Width-instance (I would use a common class for Height and Width btw, they are basicly the same)? This would enable implementations to write custom Width-elements if necessary but not force them to do so. "composition over inheritance" still applies

Comment: @jalf: it has benefits. First of all I simply think it's really cool that adding an attribute forces me to implement access methods. A second reason is that some attributes are only applied on subtypes. For example Button and ProgressMeter both have the 'value' attribute, which is however not defined on Element level. These classes having to implement the same class also enforces a consistency in method names.

Answer (score 6):

In your scenario, Element should probably not inherit from Width and Height, but instead, Width and Height should be data members of element. It's composition as opposed to is-a since arguably an Element is-not-a Width or Height but is composed of a Width and Height (and probably some other stuff too).

Comment: There is an advantage to inheritance here. If Element inherits Width then it is forced to implement the getWidth and setWidth methods. So adding an attribute implies an 'automatic' update of Element's interface.
Concerning the is-a vs has-a philosophy: I originally named these classes AttributeController, WidthController and HeightController, but I found them too verbose. If I rename them back again, is it then OK? ;)

Comment: If you have a Width, it should have everything it needs; you can expose the Width methods to the public interface of Element. 

You can also implement width/height as member classes. I don't see how you'll have elements with non-width or non-height.

Comment: I'd actually suggest doing something like class Element { Attribute Width; Attribute Height; public: Attribute width(Attribute&); Attribute height(Attribute&); }; That just makes intuitive sense to me, instead of having W/H be object types in their own right.

Comment: The variables mWidth and mHeight *are* members of Element. The classes Width and Height only provide interfaces for them.

Answer (score 2):

*Element* should inherit *Width* **only** if you need to use *Element* objects as *Width* ones . [Inheritance is not for code reuse](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.4).

Maybe would be worth for you taking a look into boost::program_options library. I like the fancy way they have for registering properties.

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to do this, I'd do a virtual inherit on Attribute. I don't think it will matter significantly, but that will minimize the duplication if it does end up mattering.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, use [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) if you are facing face a diamond problem, that is, use `public virtual` instead of just `public` on the base classes.

Secondly, it's not well defined what your `get`- and `set`-will do as there are two implementations. The only time I use multiple inheritance is when I extend pure virtual classes (aka interfaces). It's a good reason for Java to not support multiple inheritance.

Third, and more importantly, this seems like a classic case between a misunderstanding of inheritance ("is a") vs aggregation ("has a") in object orientation. You can two very simple guidelines when determining if a class should inherit another class. If you have class A and class B which inherits class A, the sentence "A is a B" should make sense. If "A has a B" sounds better, you should really consider letting B be a member of A instead.

In your case the sentences "Element is a Height" and "Element is a Width" really doesn't make sense. "Element has a Height" makes perfectly sense.

Comment: See my note at the bottom of my post about the inheritance question.

Comment: You definitely do not want Height and Width to share the same base class. So Diamond inheritance is completely Red Hearring in this context. Java's reason for not supporting it as cop out the hamstrings the developer. It was done because in-experienced developers kept getting it wrong. So rather than try and teach the correct way to do things they gave up and said lets eliminate the un-teachable people from the problem.

Comment: I cant really see why I got minus for this post. If anyone cares to enlighten me I would appreciate it.